# Returning subclass definition from a superclass function

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have two c++ classes, SuperClass & SubClass. Each of them has a set function and the function will return the class object itself at the end, as I want to execute them in a single line. The code is shown below:

```
class SuperClass
{
public:
    SuperClass& SetA(int a)
    {
        m_a = a;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("a=%i", m_a);
    }
protected:
    int m_a;
};
class SubClass : public SuperClass
{
public:
    SubClass& SetB(double b)
    {
        m_b = b;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("a=%i, b=%f", m_a, m_b);
    }
protected:
    double m_b;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SubClass().SetB(123.4).SetA(123).Print();       // Works fine
    SubClass().SetA(123).SetB(123.4).Print();       // Failed
}
```

However, the SetA() function is returning the SuperClass's definition so I can't chain it with the SetB() function declared in the SubClass.

Is there any way to make SetA() function returning the SubClass's definition? So that I can execute them in a single line.

Thanks in advance.
Elliott

**Question Update (on 2014-09-24) for CRTP approach:**
Thanks for the all comments. I think CRTP is a good way to solve this problem. However, I also want to use the SuperClass alone. Says:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    SubClass().SetB(123.4).SetA(123).Print();       // Works fine
    SubClass().SetA(123).SetB(123.4).Print();       // Failed, but works in CRTP
    SuperClass().SetA(123).Print();                 // Is CRTP able to do this?
}
```

Is the CRTP approach also help in this case?

Thanks again in advance.
Elliott

Comment: Read about [the curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

Comment: my advice is to reconsider your design. CRTP will work but your design will be a mess.

Comment: Thank you all of your comments. It seems CRTP is a good way to solve this. However, may I use the SuperClass alone under this approach?

Comment: @PiotrS.: Your answer works and so nice!  However, `std::is_same` & `std::conditional` is only available upon VC2008, am I right? I'm using VC2005, is there any alternative? Thanks again.

Comment: @Elliott: added C++98 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *It seems CRTP is a good way to solve this. However, may I use the SuperClass alone under this approach?*

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97d1778d24d3b2c0)

```
#include <type_traits>

// make it a template
template <typename T = void>
class SuperClassCRTP
{
    // determine what type SetA (and others) should return
    using CRTP = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, void>::value
                                          , SuperClassCRTP
                                          , T>::type;

public:
    // return CRTP& instead:
    CRTP& SetA(int a)
    {
        m_a = a;
        return static_cast<CRTP&>(*this); // cast the *this to desired type
    }

    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("a=%i", m_a);
    }
protected:
    int m_a;
};

class SubClass : public SuperClassCRTP<SubClass>
//               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
//               specialize the base class with self type
{
public:
    SubClass& SetB(double b)
    {
        m_b = b;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void Print()
    {
        printf("a=%i, b=%f", m_a, m_b);
    }
protected:
    double m_b;
};

// define an alias
using SuperClass = SuperClassCRTP<>;

int main()
{
    SubClass().SetB(123.4).SetA(123).Print();
    SubClass().SetA(123).SetB(123.4).Print();
    SuperClass().SetA(123).Print();
}
```

---

> *I'm using VC2005, is there any alternative?*

You can write the `is_same` and `conditional` traits on your own:

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9d4efc720c7107ba)

```
template <bool b, typename T, typename F>
struct conditional
{
    typedef F type;
};

template <typename T, typename F>
struct conditional<true, T, F>
{
    typedef T type;
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct is_same
{
    static const bool value = false;
};

template <typename T>
struct is_same<T, T>
{
    static const bool value = true;
};

template <typename T = void>
class SuperClassCRTP
{
    typedef typename conditional<is_same<T, void>::value
                                , SuperClassCRTP
                                , T>::type CRTP;

// ...

typedef SuperClassCRTP<> SuperClass;

int main()
{
    SubClass().SetB(123.4).SetA(123).Print();
    SubClass().SetA(123).SetB(123.4).Print();
    SuperClass().SetA(123).Print();    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [curiously recurring template pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) like the example below:

```
template<class T>
class SuperClass {
public:
    T& SetA(int a) {
        m_a = a;
        return *dynamic_cast<T*>(this);
    }
    virtual void Print() {
        printf("a=%i", m_a);
    }
protected:
    int m_a;
};
class SubClass : public SuperClass<SubClass>
{
public:
    SubClass& SetB(double b) {
        m_b = b;
        return *this;
    }
    virtual void Print() {
        printf("a=%i, b=%f", m_a, m_b);
    }
protected:
    double m_b;
};
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34fedf475357f8fa)

Comment: Thanks for your promptly reply. However, may I use the SuperClass alone via this CRTP method?

Comment: So how is your suggestion?   I was thinking about to use template function on SetA() & SetB() instead of using CRTP, so that every time the functions are called I have to specify the return type. But this seems not a good approach... :(

Comment: Oops... sorry for bothering... take your time. Thanks!

Comment: @Elliott No sorry, I couldn't find a clean way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to the solutions using compile-time polymorphism you can also achieve a similar result using runtime polymorphism with virtual functions. For that you'd need to declare all functions used in derived classes already as `virtual` in the base class (possibly with dummy implementations), and then override them in the derived classes.

```
#include <cstdio>

class SuperClass {
public:
  SuperClass &SetA(int a) {
    m_a = a;
    return *this;
  }
  virtual void Print() { printf("a=%i", m_a); }
  virtual SuperClass &SetB(double b) { return *this; };

protected:
  int m_a;
};

class SubClass : public SuperClass {
public:
  SubClass &SetB(double b) {
    m_b = b;
    return *this;
  }
  virtual void Print() { printf("a=%i, b=%f", m_a, m_b); }

protected:
  double m_b;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  SubClass().SetB(123.4).SetA(123).Print();
  printf("\n");
  SubClass().SetA(123).SetB(123.4).Print();
}
```

Comment: um... however, I would rather keep the SuperClass sealed when adding a new SubClass or a new function in the SubClass... this way seems not able to do so. Anyway, thanks a lot for your comment. :)